# Tomcat and maxPostSize value

Tags: tomcat, memory

During test using default value of maxPostSize in Tomcat connector, we observed the system gets an error when the http body is greater than 2MB. We tried to set the maxPostSize at 20MB, and this is OK now. As my system is supposed to have multiple connections I have the following two questions without answers.

- Do you know if the memory consumption is reserved at the value of maxPostSize for each connection?
- If I set maxPostSize value to 0 or -1, the size is unlimited, but what is the impact on Java (Tomcat memory management )?

Answer (score 1):

For requests with a payload larger than 8192 bytes, the memory necessary to store the body is allocated when needed (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/fefe4de781449493000a633488aa11198434cf3e/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#L3238)).

However, since Servlet 3.0, if your application requires large file uploads, consider posting them as `multipart/form-data` and use the `@MultipartConfig` annotation (cf. [Jakarta EE tutorial](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#uploading-files-with-jakarta-servlet-technology)). The request parameters transmitted as files **do not count** towards the `maxPostSize` limit and are written to a temporary file whenever they are larger than a configurable limit.

Therefore you might approximately consider `maxPostSize` as the maximum heap memory required to store the parameters of a request.